# Angular2: Get URL without params as string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm building a web-app using Angular2 (v. 2.1.1) for the frontend.

Is it possible to get the URL, *without* any parameters, as a string?

If my URL is `foo/bar/1/2/3` then I need way of getting `foo/bar`.
The URL is not static, e.g. the method must also support URLs like `/another/url/1/2`

I've tried using the `ActivatedRoute.url`, but it only returns `['bar', '1', '2', '3']`. For some reason it does not contain the beginning (`foo/`).

I've also tried using the `Location.url`, but it returns the entire URL.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I also need to get only the path without the parameter. did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use substring?

```
this.router.url.substring(0,7)
```

This should return foo/bar

Comment: Won't work. I need a method that work on all URLs. Please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick work around, remove all numbers after the backslash "/" :

```
var url = "foo/bar/1/2/3";
url = url.replace(/(\/([0-9]+))*/g, '');
```